# Tags: price vs pricing vs price-theory

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed on a recent question that we have at least three price-related tags [price](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price), [pricing](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pricing) and [price-theory](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price-theory). None have any usage information attached right now. Is more than one price tag necessary and if so when?

Comment: For reference, 81 questions are tagged [tag:price], 35 [tag:price-theory], and 51 [tag:pricing].

Answer (score 3):

As a first step to answering the question, I am creating this community wiki to figure out what the usage descriptions *would* be if we decided to keep all three tags. Then we can take stock of whether they are independently useful.

Everyone should feel free to refine or change the definitions.

**Price** (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price))

> A price is the quantity of payment or compensation given by one party to another in return for one unit of goods or services.

**Pricing**

> The problem of determining the approriate price for one or more goods and services.

**Price theory** (from [Glen Weyl](https://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2015/07/what-is-price-theory.html), who identifies himself as probably the only price theorist under the age of 40)

> Analysis that reduces rich and often incompletely specified models into ‘prices’ sufficient to characterize approximate solutions to simple (e.g. one-dimensional policy) allocative problems.